# MS Outlook 365 HTML Tables VALIGN

Tags: html, outlook, valign

Tables in HTML Email not displaying correctly.

The cells will not Vertically Align at the top.

Code in HTML that did not work.

```
<TD valign=top>
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain better what is your question?

Comment: I Self-answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Create a table in MS OUTLOOK 365

[Table Inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHSus.png)

Email it to yourself.

[Click here to view it in a web browser message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkUbE.png)

Now you have the correct HTML code from Microsoft.

Code in HTML **WORKING **

```
<table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>

<td width=156 valign=top style='width:116.85pt;border-top:1px solid blue; windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
```

I added the border-top:1px solid blue for clarity to separate but not necessary.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHSus.png)